# Bootstrap 3 Columns Not Getting Rendered as expected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning boot strap to build my own page. Here is the snippet.

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- container-fluid is taking of the padding towards the end, lets go with just the container. -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><img id="photo" src="tom-cruise.jpg" alt="Pavan Dittakavi"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">HELLO,
MY NAME IS KAMIL24YO AND THIS IS MY RESUME/CV</div>

            </div>

            <div id="seperator"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="my_header">
                            //ABOUT ME
                        </div>                   

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, non, dolorem, cumque distinctio magni quam expedita velit laborum sunt amet facere tempora ut fuga aliquam ad asperiores voluptatem dolorum! Quasi.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="my_header">
                            //EDUCATION
                        </div>                   

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, non, dolorem, cumque distinctio magni quam expedita velit laborum sunt amet facere tempora ut fuga aliquam ad asperiores voluptatem dolorum! Quasi.
                        </p>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class="row">
                <!-- -->                
                        <div class="my_header">
                            //ABOUT ME
                        </div>                   

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, non, dolorem, cumque distinctio magni quam expedita velit laborum sunt amet facere tempora ut fuga aliquam ad asperiores voluptatem dolorum! Quasi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        </p>
                <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            


            <br/>


<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="my_header">
                            //ABOUT ME2
                        </div>                   

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, non, dolorem, cumque distinctio magni quam expedita velit laborum sunt amet facere tempora ut fuga aliquam ad asperiores voluptatem dolorum! Quasi.
                        </p>
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class="row">
                <!-- -->                
                        <div class="my_header">
                            //ABOUT ME
                        </div>                   

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, non, dolorem, cumque distinctio magni quam expedita velit laborum sunt amet facere tempora ut fuga aliquam ad asperiores voluptatem dolorum! Quasi.
                        </p>
                <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>         
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS file:

```
#photo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:3px solid #021a40;
}

#seperator {
  border-top: double;
  color: #ededed;
}

.my_header {

        color: #EC7263;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

body {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Tahoma;
}

.shape{
  text-align:left;
  background-color:rgba(3,78,136,0.7);
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  color:white;
  margin:20px auto;
  position:relative;
}
```

What I have noticed is that col-lg-7 and col-lg-5 or for that matter col-lg-2 and col-lg-10 are not rendered as columns in Bootstrap. Can you please let me know where I am missing - I have a feeling that the div ordering or usage of rows and containers is missing something.

As a side note, I also see that on Chrome the distortion is more - the columns are not getting rendered at all, but on Firefox it renders to some extent - for example the first few columns.

> > Edit: My problem now is that I am trying to build a clone for http://kamsolutions.pl/projects/resume/ and in my implementation, I see that the resulting HTML file has columns and rows mixed up and not getting rendered as expected. Here is the picture that I am referring to.

[image: Snippet of the webpage and the white space problem]

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: not rendered as columns in Bootstrap-- means??

Comment: Your code is giving correct result. What are you wanting actually?

Answer (score 0):

You have a row, within which you have two columns, col-lg-7 and col-lg-5. Within the col-lg-7 you have two additional rows, whereas within the col-lg-5 you only have one row. That's where your blank space is coming from.